# IE Mode in Edge for websites compatible with IE versions older than IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a web application which is only compatible with IE 7 to 10 .   Compatibility view has to be set in IE if the application is accessed through IE 11.

If I set the compatibility setting in IE, and if i access the app in edge in IE mode, app works fine. Because it is acting as IE 7.

Question is if the computer used to access do not have IE installed, what is the option to have the app working in edge with IE mode.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling IE 11 is one of the prerequisites for using Edge IE mode, so you cannot use IE mode in Edge without enabling IE 11 in the windows feature.

Just refer to this doc: [Edge Ie mode - Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#prerequisites).